# How to determine valid chess moves?

Tags: chess

I am trying to understand the algorithms behind determining valid moves for each chess piece. The specific issue I am having is determining when a piece cannot move past a certain point because it is being blocked by a piece of its own colour or is able to take a piece of the opposite colour but cannot move past that point.

The simple algorithms I have for each piece are:

> Valid King move, if the piece moves from (X1, Y1) to (X2, Y2), the
>   move is valid if and only if |X2-X1|<=1 and |Y2-Y1|<=1.
>
> Valid Bishop move, if the piece moves from (X1, Y1) to (X2, Y2), the
>   move is valid if and only if |X2-X1|=|Y2-Y1|.
>
> Valid Rook move, if the piece moves from (X1, Y1) to (X2, Y2), the
>   move is valid if and only if X2=X1 or Y2=Y1.
>
> Valid Queen move, a queen's move is valid if it is either a valid
>   bishop or rook move.
>
> Valid Knight move, if the piece moves from (X1, Y1) to (X2, Y2), the
>   move is valid if and only if (|X2-X1|=1 and |Y2-Y1|=2) or (|X2-X1|=2
>   and |Y2-Y1|=1).
>
> Valid Pawn move, if the piece moves from (X1, Y1) to (X2, Y2), the
>   move is valid if and only if X2=X1 and Y2-Y1=1 (only for a white
>   pawn).

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I think overall is ok, but you are not taking into account the following: 
1. Double movement of the pawn if is in the 2nd or 7th row.
2. On peasant eating.
3. Castling.

Comment: Lots more cases that you're not considering - like not moving a king into check, or exposing check for your king.  But in answer to your question about whether the piece's path is blocked, you'd have to check each square along the path, to see if it's empty.  You'll need lots of conditions and some kind of loop.

Comment: If you're comfortable with bit twiddling, have a look at bitboards, for example [here](http://www.chessengine.co.uk/2016/04/05/what-is-a-bitboard/). They are much more efficient and elegant once you get used to them. For sliding pieces (rooks, queens and bishops) you would treat each direction separately. For horizontal moves, you look at the occupancy of the rank (8 squares that can be empty, white or black, so no more than 3^8 = 6561 possiblities) and you precompute the possible moves for each occupancy and each starting file of your piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the board state into account for that.
I think the common way to do it would be checking if each cell on the path is empty or not.

```
    public enum PieceColor { Black, White }
    public interface IBoard
    {
        bool IsEmpty(int x, int y);
        PieceColor GetPieceColor(int x, int y);
    }

    IBoard board;

    bool BishopCanMove(PieceColor bishopColor, int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY)
    {
        int pathLength = Mathf.Abs(toX - fromX);
        if (pathLength != Mathf.Abs(toY - fromY)) return false; // Not diagonal
        // Also validate if the coordinates are in the 0-7 range

        // Check all cells before the target
        for (int i = 1; i < pathLength; i++)
        {
            int x = fromX + i;
            int y = fromY + i;

            if(board.IsEmpty(x, y)) continue; // No obstacles here: keep going
            else return false; // Obstacle found before reaching target: the move is invalid
        }

        // Check target cell
        if (board.IsEmpty(toX, toY)) return true; // No piece: move is valid

        // There's a piece here: the move is valid only if we can capture
        return board.GetPieceColor(toX, toY) == bishopColor;
    }
```

The `IBoard` interface is there just to show the point. You should have a board state exposing those informations in some way.

Comment: I don't really understand why the for loop that checks that the squares in between aren't occupied works. Shouldn't we need four of them to check each possible direction? Adding 1 to each coordinate should only work if the only diagonal is upper right.

Comment: This was simplified to show the point.
You can still avoid having four loops by defining `int stepDirectionX = Math.Sign(toX - fromX);` and same for `stepDirectionY` and add those instead of 1

Comment: Thanks, that helps.

Comment: No. The validity of the move is determined by:1-Square not occumied by own figure, 2-move doesn't expose own king to check, 3 - Move-position for this figure is valid at all, 4 - Rock and King were not moved before (rochade), 5 - King wouldn't cross the atack line of other figure (rochade), 6 - Pawn was not moved before (en passe). So a little bit more complicated.